# A working paper or a discussion paper or something else?

Tags: citations

I have some papers from google which I don't know to what type they belong: a working paper or a discussion paper or something else? I need this for my bibliography

Below are some examples of such cases.

The first one has an abbreviation JEL Classifications, but is this enough to refer this to Journal of Economic Literature?

The second one has nothing at all.

Can someone give me a hint? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: This one has an abbreviation JEL Classifications, but is this enough to refer this to Journal of Economic Literature?]

[image: This one has nothing at all]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JEL classifications are just that: classifications. Anyone can put such a classification on his paper, and it doesn't have anything to do with publishing in the JEL - it's more like a keyword.

To your question: I don't think there really is such a big difference between a working paper (which is work in progress, typically distributed to be discussed) and a discussion paper (which is work in progress, typically distributed to be discussed). All of these are essentially manuscripts under preparation for submission to a refereed journal (in CS, a conference). So I would file all of these under "non-reviewed papers".

Comment: Thanks! I have For the bibliography, are there any requirements for "non-reviewed papers"? For example I use the following guidelines: http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/pack/bibtex/btxdoc/node6.html

http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/pack/bibtex/btxdoc/node7.html

But no working paper category is listed there...

Comment: "unpublished" in your first link would fit best.

Answer (score 0):

Very rarely you will find the full reference in the paper.  To retrieve complete references use google scholar  (which provides even different versions of the same paper) and double check in doubt. You can also try indexer services provided by your university such as worldcat or summon.